# SEVERE: Error occurred while building server: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An error occured while executing shell command:

Tags: selendroid

I am new in Android and I am tring to run this example:

https://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-selendroid.html

I am facing the following issue:

```
io.selendroid.exceptions.AndroidDeviceException: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An error occured while executing shell command: D:\android-sdksEclipse\Android\Sdk\tools\android.bat list avds
at io.selendroid.android.impl.DefaultAndroidEmulator.listAvailableAvds(DefaultAndroidEmulator.java:113)
at io.selendroid.server.model.DeviceStore.initAndroidDevices(DeviceStore.java:104)
at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.initAndroidDevices(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:160)
at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:83)
at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.initializeSelendroidServer(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:61)
at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:50)
at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.launchServer(SelendroidLauncher.java:49)
at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.launchSelendroid(SelendroidLauncher.java:73)
at com.guru.test.Guru99Test.setUp(Guru99Test.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:326)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An error occured while executing shell command: D:\android-sdksEclipse\Android\Sdk\tools\android.bat list avds
at io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:49)
at `io.selendroid.android.impl.DefaultAndroidEmulator.listAvailableAvds(DefaultAndroidEmulator.java:111)`
```

... 27 more
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: **************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat
and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat

Invalid or unsupported command "list avds"

Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk

... 29 more
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @beforesuite setUp

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: io.selendroid.exceptions.AndroidDeviceException: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An error occured while executing shell command: D:\android-sdksEclipse\Android\Sdk\tools\android.bat list avds
at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.launchServer(SelendroidLauncher.java:60)
at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.launchSelendroid(SelendroidLauncher.java:73)
at com.guru.test.Guru99Test.setUp(Guru99Test.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:326)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.AndroidDeviceException: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An error occured while executing shell command: D:\android-sdksEclipse\Android\Sdk\tools\android.bat list avds
at io.selendroid.android.impl.DefaultAndroidEmulator.listAvailableAvds(DefaultAndroidEmulator.java:113)
at io.selendroid.server.model.DeviceStore.initAndroidDevices(DeviceStore.java:104)
at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.initAndroidDevices(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:160)
at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:83)
at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.initializeSelendroidServer(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:61)
at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:50)
at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.launchServer(SelendroidLauncher.java:49)
```

... 21 more
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An error occured while executing shell command: D:\android-sdksEclipse\Android\Sdk\tools\android.bat list avds
at io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:49)
at io.selendroid.android.impl.DefaultAndroidEmulator.listAvailableAvds(DefaultAndroidEmulator.java:111)
... 27 more
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: **************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat
and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat

Invalid or unsupported command "list avds"

Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk

... 29 more
SKIPPED: selendroidTest

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: io.selendroid.exceptions.AndroidDeviceException: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An error occured while executing shell command: D:\android-sdksEclipse\Android\Sdk\tools\android.bat list avds
at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.launchServer(SelendroidLauncher.java:60)
at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.launchSelendroid(SelendroidLauncher.java:73)
at com.guru.test.Guru99Test.setUp(Guru99Test.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:326)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.AndroidDeviceException: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An error occured while executing shell command: D:\android-sdksEclipse\Android\Sdk\tools\android.bat list avds
at io.selendroid.android.impl.DefaultAndroidEmulator.listAvailableAvds(DefaultAndroidEmulator.java:113)
at io.selendroid.server.model.DeviceStore.initAndroidDevices(DeviceStore.java:104)
at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.initAndroidDevices(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:160)
at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:83)
at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.initializeSelendroidServer(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:61)
at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:50)
at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.launchServer(SelendroidLauncher.java:49)
... 21 more
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An error occured while executing shell command: D:\android-sdksEclipse\Android\Sdk\tools\android.bat list avds
at io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:49)
at io.selendroid.android.impl.DefaultAndroidEmulator.listAvailableAvds(DefaultAndroidEmulator.java:111)
```

... 27 more
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: **************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat
and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat

Invalid or unsupported command "list avds"

Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk

## ... 29 more

Default test
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0

Could you please help me out?

Comment: Do you get the solution to this problem @RapsonGany ??? If yes, kindly share it...